# Linear algebra matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, diagonalization

I was unable to prove the following statement.
Let $A,B$ are both matrices of $n\times n$ of real numbers. We know that the matrix $ A$ is invertible.
Then, we have to prove that there are $n$ diferent $\lambda_i$ so that the matrix $C=\lambda_iA+B $is invertible.
($\lambda_i$ are real numbers)

Comment: Perhaps you meant $C$ is **non** invertible?

Comment: This problem was in an exam i took, and i'm pretty sure it said that C was invertible, but maybe there was a mistake in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to have some issues:

If $C$ is supposed to be invertible:
It suffices that $\lambda I + BA^{-1}$ is invertible. As long as $\lambda$ is not negative of any of the eigenvalues of $BA^{-1}$ this matrix is invertible. So there are infinitely many valid $\lambda$s.

If $C$ is supposed to be non-invertible:
Take $A=B=I$, then any $C$ is a multiple of the identity and it can only be non-invertible when $\lambda = -1$. So there is only one $\lambda$ satisfying the claim not $n$ **different** $\lambda$s.

Answer (score 1):

Uzing the [QZ (generalized Schur) decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QZ_decomposition), we see that
$$A = QSZ^*, \quad B = QTZ^*,$$
for some unitary $Q$ and $Z$, and upper triangular $S$ and $T$. Then
$$C = \lambda_i A + B = Q(\lambda_iS + T)Z^*.$$
**Edit:** As egreg corrected my initial silly statement, $C$ is invertible if and only if $X := \lambda_iS+T$ is invertible (since unitary matrices $Q$ and $Z$ are invertible), and $X$ is invertible if and only if all its diagonal elements (which also happen to be its eigenvalues, because $X$ is upper triangular) are non-zero.

Comment: I don't see why the diagonal elements of $\lambda_iS+T$ are the eigenvalues of $C$, unless $Q=Z$. However, $C$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda_iS+T$ is.

Comment: @egreg Let's attribute my temporary insanity to today's heat. <blush> Thank you.